# Futurama "Decision 3012" time paradox

Tags: time-travel, futurama, paradox

I know this is old but I can't find anything that answers my question.

So at the end of the episode, Bender explains that the reason Travers disappeared is because if Nixon never got elected, then Travers never would have been sent back in time. But by disappearing and allowing Nixon to win, the uprising would happen and Travers would have been sent back in time.

Did he just completely cease to exist? Even then, the remaining humans would've just sent someone else back. I don't know, I might be overthinking it but it just seems lazy.